# Images from Twitter API rendering as 1px x 1px

Tags: css, image, twitter

I'm building a simple application that interfaces with the Twitter API, and part of it involves displaying tweets. I'm pulling the URL for the profile pictures just fine, but when I use it as the src for an img tag, it renders as 1px x 1px. If I just paste the link into an address bar it displays the image exactly as I would expect. I naturally assumed my css was at fault, but literally any image that doesn't come from Twitter's image storage works fine.

Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/7Lv8g8uz/2/

**HTML**

```
<!-- URL pulled from Twitter API-->
<figure class="image is-64x64">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/429198033666863104/KGl1cz6-_normal.jpeg" alt="Image">
</figure>

<!-- Random image from Google -->
<figure class="image is-64x64">
  <img src="https://play.google.com/books/publish/u/0/static/images/google-search.png" alt="Image">
</figure>
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
.image {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.is-64x64 {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Is this a known problem with Twitter images, or am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Which browser are you using? I tried in FF, Chrome, Opera - all of them rendered the images in that fiddle just fine.

Comment: I'm using Chrome on OS X. Maybe something is weird with my Chrome config? I tried disabling all of my extensions with no luck. I'll try a fresh install and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Disconnect is blocking images from Twitter's image storage, but I'm guessing it is turned off behind the scenes on the actual Twitter domain (which is why images were rendering fine there). I knew it would be something simple!